# How is made a background animation in cheshirecat.inthehiddencity.com

Tags: javascript, animation, 3d

I have a problem with identity how does work background 3D animation in cheshirecat.inthehiddencity.com. I will be appreciate for your ideas.

Comment: What is the issue with the code that you have tried to resolve the inquiry?

Answer (score 0):

The background animation is a [WebGL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL) program, which allows you (if your browser supports WebGL) to render 3D animations. For further information see [WebGL Homepage](https://www.khronos.org/webgl/)